# Aplying SSL in Tomcat

Tags: tomcat, ssl

I' m trying to apply SSL on Tomcat. As I have understood it is 2 steps process. The 1st step is to setup the keyplace file which I made it and the 2nd is to modify accordingly the server.xml file. 
The first part worked succesfully

The part of server.xml regarding is as follow :

```
<!-- Define a SSL HTTP/1.1 Connector on port 8443
     This connector uses the JSSE configuration, when using APR, the
     connector should be using the OpenSSL style configuration
     described in the APR documentation -->

<Connector SSLEnabled="true" acceptCount="100" clientAuth="false"
disableUploadTimeout="true" enableLookups="false" maxThreads="25"
port="8443" keystoreFile="/temp/keyplace" keystorePass="myPass"
protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol" scheme="https"
secure="true" sslProtocol="TLS"/>
```

but when I try to call apache the server tries to connect and eventually times out

Thanks for any answer

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, check to see is your keystore correctly set up.

Looking at your configuration file, the following command should tell you whether your certificate has been created or not - **keytool -list -keystore /temp/keyplace**

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I already did this and is perfectly fine. It produced the fingerprint on cmd

Answer (score 0):

instead of keystoreFile="/temp/keyplace" it should be keystoreFile="c:/temp/keyplace"